# Service started twice in android

Tags: android, service

I have a service that started twice every time I call it in my fragment

This is the fragment, the service is started whenever the application stops

TestFragment

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
 
        getActivity().startService(intent);
        getActivity().bindService(intent,boundServiceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private ServiceConnection boundServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            BoundService.MyBinder binderBridge = (BoundService.MyBinder) service;
            boundService = binderBridge.getService();
            boundService.refresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            isBound = false;
            boundService = null;
        }
    };
```

This is the service
BoundService

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("ServiceState","Started");

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Logcat

```
2021-01-11 16:15:37.118 5043-5043/com.example.shelfmanagementsystem I/Service: Started
2021-01-11 16:15:37.124 5043-5043/com.example.shelfmanagementsystem I/Service: Started
```

Why is this happening? thanks in advance

Comment: what is this `boundService.refresh()` ?

Comment: I'm new to android so I'm not quite sure, but you start the service **and** you bind it. Try skipping one of those.